# AWS API Gateway / Axios / Lambda Authorizer - Unauthorized & Authentication headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a single portal app that will allow end users to access multiple apps/resources in AWS - that might be a dash app running in a fargate task or simply a button that triggers a state machine (for example).

I am using React, AWS Amplify (for the single page entry), Cognito, API Gateway (HTTP), Axios Interceptors.

Here is how my interceptor is configured:

```
    const interceptor = aws4Interceptor(
        {
          region: "eu-west-1",
          service: "execute-api",
        },
        {
          accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: sessionToken
        })
    axios.interceptors.request.use(interceptor);
```

And here is my `axios.get`:

```
axios.get( 'https://abcdefg.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myapi/')
          .then( response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.request.responseURL);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

While this will work, and I will be able to see the content in the console - let's assume that this route has a lambda integration that prints something - this is not really what I am aiming for.

What I really want (and let's assume that the API Gateway route has an integration with a dash app running in fargate), I would like to open such web application in the current/new tab.

So, I am not really just to pull some data from a database or something, but really I want to be able to open a web app if needed.

Q: Is this even possible to make?

Currently:

- using Postman, the request (using AWS Signature) will be successful
- same applies with the case above, but I cannot find a way to open the route integration as a single app - I can only print it's content

When doing `axios.get` it is possible to see all the required headers in the request: authorization, x-amz-date, x-amz-security-token, but then we would need some kind of "redirect" to actually open the web app - and here is where we have problems since the new request won't have such headers so we will get 401 Unauthorized errors.

Is there a way to go around this? Authentication cookies? URL token?

Thank you